# Is second order derivative equal to the product of first order derivative?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, hessian-matrix

Given a real-valued function $f(x_1,x_2)$, we define the function $h(x_1,x_2) = |f(x_1,x_2)|^2$. I want to calculate the Hessian of $h$. Is the following expression correct?

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2}=2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1 } \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2 }
\end{align*}

If it is not true, in which condition, it can become true?

Comment: If and only if $\partial^2 f/\partial x_1\partial x_2=0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin as a function, but the equation could hold at some points (namely those for which $f=0$). Although maybe someday we'll live in a world where $a+b= a$ doesn't imply $b=0$ ...

Comment: @s.harp That's what I get fir doing this in my head. The “iff” was plain wrong. Let's make it correct by putting in the product with $f$ as you suggest.